# Plotting as a group using Panda and Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I want to plot as a group using Panda and Matplotlib.  THe plot would look like this kind of grouping:

[image]

Now let's assume I have a data file example.csv:

```
first,second,third,fourth,fifth,sixth
-42,11,3,La_c-,D
-42,21,2,La_c-,D0
-42,31,2,La_c-,D
-42,122,3,La_c-,L
```

`print(df.head())` of the above is:

```
   first   second   third  fourth  fifth   sixth
0    -42       11       3   La_c-      D     NaN
1    -42       21       2   La_c-     D0     NaN
2    -42       31       2   La_c-      D     NaN
3    -42      122       3   La_c-      L     NaN
```

In my case, on the x-axis, each group will consist of (first and the second column), just like in the above plot they have pies_2018,pies_2019,pies_2020.

To do that, I have tried to plot a single column first:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python3
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    #from scipy import stats
    #import ast
    filename = 'example.csv'
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    print(df.head())
    df.plot(kind='bar', x=df.columns[1],y=df.columns[2],figsize=(12, 4))
    plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(bottom=0.35)
```

I get a plot like this:

[image]

Now the problem is when I want to make a group I get the following error:

```
     raise ValueError("x must be a label or position")
ValueError: x must be a label or position
```

The thing is that I was considering the numbers as a label.

The code I used:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#from scipy import stats
#import ast
filename = 'example.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
print(df.head())
df.plot(kind='bar', x=["first", "second"],y="third",figsize=(12, 4))
plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(bottom=0.35)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

If I can plot the first and second as a group, in addition to the legends, I will want to mention the fifth column in the "first" bar and the sixth column in the "second" bar.

Comment: we don't have your CSV so you need to hard-code your dataframe into the example

Comment: I have added the csv file.

Comment: your column names have leading spaces

Comment: my point was if your CSV was that way, it would explain the key error

Comment: @PaulH, I have updated the question. It's showing the error now "ValueError: x must be a label or position". But the thing is that I wanted to use the number as index or label in the x direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You can play around but this gives you the stacked bars in groups.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

first = [-42, -42, -42, -42] #Use your column df['first']
second = [11, 21, 31, 122] #Use your column df['second']
third = [3, 2, 2, 3]
x = np.arange(len(third))
width = 0.25  #bar width

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
bar1 = ax.bar(x, third, width, label='first', color='blue')
bar2 = ax.bar(x + width, third, width, label='second', color='green')
ax.set_ylabel('third')
ax.set_xticks(x)
rects = ax.patches
labels = [str(i) for i in zip(first, second)] #You could use the columns df['first'] instead of the lists

for rect, label in zip(rects, labels):
    height = rect.get_height()
    ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height, label,
            ha='center', va='bottom')
ax.legend()
```

EDITED & NEW Plot -

[image]

Comment: I think I wanted the x-axis would be from multiple columns which only be used as indices (not the Y value!), but the Y-axis value for both of the groups would be the same and will come from another column.   As an example,  if in your example I think "first" and "label" will be grouped together and the "second" will represent the Y value for both of them. Since we have only one Y value, which is second, both column in one group will have same Y value. Let me know if I was not clear?

Comment: I didn't understand actually. In the example I mentioned, I have plotted the values in two columns - first and second. There are four rows, so 4 grouped/stacked bars. The x-axis basically denotes the row number (labels) and the y-axis denotes the column values (-42 for all first).

It is similar to the plot you mentioned in the question.

Comment: If you look at my question, I grouped two columns in the x-axis, but I wanted to have only one column value on the y axis for both of them. Multiple columns in the x-axis will have the same value on the Y-axis. ` df.plot(kind='bar', x=["first", "second"],y="third",figsize=(12, 4))`

Comment: SORRY I will try to improve the question. My intention was to get the only indices from the multiple columns along the x-axis, but all the columns will represent only another column. I'm considering the X-axis columns for indices purposes only.  They won't have any Y value from the same column, but from a different column which is defined by y="third".

Comment: Hi, check the edited answer please and see if this is what is needed. The y-values are now common i.e. the column "third" while you have stacked bars in "first" and "second". Hope this is what you wanted. :-)

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was expecting. Can we give the index number to both of the bars in each group? FOr example, the first  group will have a name like (-42,11)

Comment: Hi check the updated answer. If this works, do mark it as the answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

using `ax.patches` you can achieve it.

**df:**

```
    a   b   c   d
a1  66  92  98  17
a2  83  57  86  97
a3  96  47  73  32
```

---

```
ax = df.T.plot(width=0.8, kind='bar',y=df.columns,figsize=(10,5))
for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate(str(round(p.get_height(),2)), (p.get_x() * 1.005, p.get_height() * 1.005),color='green')
  
ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])
```

---

[image]